# Facebook Graph API key error

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am working on a python AppEngine application with Facebook login. I want to be able to access a logged-in user's friends' bios (their "about me" information).

Having requested/saved changes for all of the permissions I need on the Facebook developer's dashboard, I can successfully make calls like this:

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields="name")
for friend in friends["data"]:
    print friend["name"]
```

But trying to access the about me, as specified by the "bio" field in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/), results in a key error:

```
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields="name,bio")
    for friend in friends["data"]:
        print friend["bio"]
```

AppEngine log when running on local host:

```
 File "/Users/nicole/aggie-harmony/main.py", line 154, in get
    user = self.current_user
  File "/Users/nicole/aggie-harmony/main.py", line 108, in current_user
    bio = friend["bio"] 
KeyError: 'bio'
INFO     2013-11-16 02:59:27,243 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have experimented with other fields, and it seems like anything that requires an access token will generate a key error (although the docs actually seem to have been updated mere HOURS before this question was posted...and they now suggest that "Other fields that have been explicitly set to public visibility can also be retrieved without an access token"...in my test user, the bio is indeed public!)

Unless I am just missing something syntax-wise, is this indeed a token issue? My app is based on the example [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py) and basically obtains/uses the access token like this (auth stuff was generated previously and stored in its own file):

```
...
cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, auth.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 
                                       auth.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
...
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
...
```

Interestingly enough, the app doesn't pop up a permission box for the user after the log-in area, which might support my hunch...

Comment: First check if it works in FB Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer Then try to implement it in your app.

Comment: It does if you generate the proper access tokens. I suspect I need to do that pythonically and somehow get the permissions incorporated with the cookie...but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: It was indeed an issue of permissions. In my adapted example html file, I just needed to change this:

```
function doLogin() {  
                FB.login(function(response) {} , {perms:''});
}
```

...to this:

```
function doLogin() {  
                FB.login(function(response) {} , {perms:'user_about_me,friends_about_me,user_likes,friends_likes,user_relationship_details,friends    _relationship_details,user_relationships,friends_relationships, user_education_history, friends_education_history'});
}
```

Facebook takes care of the rest with the proper oauth dialog, etc.